# How to get keyword by which select query selects result?

Tags: mysql, keyword, match-against

How to get exact keywords by which select query selects result set by using full text search MATCH() AGAINST() in MySQL

```
SELECT ... , MATCH(table_column) AGAINST("'LIST_OF_KEYWORDS' IN BOOLEAN MODE") AS relevance
```

Now here I want to get the exact matched keyword(s)

Comment: Please edit the question to show the query you are referring to.

Comment: I have edited my post with the query. Will you please provide some solution :)

Answer (score 0):

From MySQL docs:

> Find rows that contain the exact phrase “some words” (for example, rows that contain “some words of wisdom” but not “some noise words”). Note that the “"” characters that enclose the phrase are operator characters that delimit the phrase. They are not the quotation marks that enclose the search string itself.

Find exact phrase:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table 
WHERE MATCH(table_column) AGAINST('"PUT_YOUR_PHRASE"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance
```

Find at least one of the keywords:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table 
WHERE MATCH(table_column) AGAINST('KEYWORD1 KEYWORD2' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance
```

Find at BOTH keywords:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table 
WHERE MATCH(table_column) AGAINST('+KEYWORD1 +KEYWORD2' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance
```

Comment: Need to show the matched keywords, by which the row has been populated. So your answer is not useful.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide some examples, i think you want the third solution, to match all keywords. Remember that if you want to get an exact phrase need to enclose your search in double quotes